# Error with length in Javascript when i use multiple for loop

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
for (let i = 0; i < element.details.length; i++) {
  let myElement = element.details[i];
  let Length = myElement.items.length;
  element.details[i].price= 0; // 1

  for (let e = 0; e < b; e++) {
    myElement.items[e].price= 0; //2
  }
}
```

1 & 2 works fine, but by the end, i got an error after function 2 saying `Cannot read property length of undefined'`

and makes the rest of the code with bad issues. `

Any orientation please ? Thank you

Comment: Either f.details or a.items is undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "*after function 2*"? You're not really using any `function`s here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a null check would do just fine for you

```
let c = f.details ? f.details.length : 0; //null check
for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
  let a = f.details[i];
  let b = a.items ? a.items.length : 0; //null check
  f.details[i].prixv = 0; // Function 1

  for (let e = 0; e < b; e++) {
    a.items[e].prixv = 0; //Function 2
  }
}
```